# How can I scroll bottom when overflow-y:scroll and height:100vh

Tags: javascript, css

Is it possible to scroll bottom when overflow-y:scroll and height:100vh.

css

```
#content {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

js

```
var content = document.getElementById('content');
window.scrollTo(0, content.scrollHeight);
```

codepen
https://codepen.io/betchi/pen/zjBwgx

Comment: Use `content.scrollTop=content.scrollHeight` instead of `window.scrollTo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example you are scrolling the entire window.
It looks like what you want to do is scroll the content and not the window like this:

```
content.scrollTo(0, content.scrollHeight);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the property scrollTop of the element you want to scroll.

Change your function to this:

```
function canNotScroll(){
  var content = document.getElementById('content');
  content.scrollTop = content.scrollHeight;
}
```